# C# don't understand byte[]

Tags: c#, byte

I've never programmed in C# and I can't figure out one line of code because I just don't understand what it does.

```
public static void Main()
    {
      
            String s = "a55a0019833400e280699400005002f172ad27fd8401120d0a";
              
            s = s.Replace(" ", "");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[s.Length / 2];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2) {
              
            buffer[i / 2] = (byte)Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, 2), 16);
            
      }

byte[] buffer = new byte[s.Length / 2]; //byte[] buffer is it array?

buffer[i / 2] = (byte)Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, 2), 16); //I don't understand the notation buffer[ i / 2]
```

Comment: Yes `byte[]` is an array and `[i / 2]` is the index of the array. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte?view=net-6.0#representing-a-byte-as-a-string

Answer (score 1):

byte[] is an array.

The buffer[i / 2] is there to fill the buffer array at the right position. Because in the for loop you increment `i` by `+= 2` but you dont want to fill the array at the position `buffer[i]` which would be equal to `buffer[0]`,`buffer[2]`,`buffer[4]`,`buffer[6]`,`buffer[8]`...

With the `buffer[i / 2]` you get `buffer[0]`,`buffer[1]`,`buffer[2]`,`buffer[3]`,`buffer[4]`... instead.

Comment: To be more clear, every 2 characters from the string variable is taken [hexadecimal representation ] and converted to byte and stored in the byte array named `buffer`